# Author comment count in author page

Tags: users, comments, author, count

hi i want to show author comment count in author page. this code can display current user comment count but i dont want current user i need any user please help me

```
/* user commnet count */
    function commentCount() {
        global $wpdb, $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $userId = $current_user->ID;

        $count = $wpdb->get_var('
                 SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) 
                 FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' 
                 WHERE user_id = "' . $userId . '"');
        echo 'Şərh sayı ' . $count ;
    }
      <?php commentCount(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is to add an param:

```
/* user commnet count */
function get_comment_count( $user_ID ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM {$wpdb->comments} WHERE user_id = %d ", $user_ID )
    );
    return $count;
}
<?php echo get_comment_count( <USER_ID> ); ?>
```

PS. I've added some proper escaping in your query also, so this code is not vulnerable any more...

### But you can also use...

WordPress already has its own way of doing it, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel... You can use:

```
$count = get_comments( array(
    'user_id' => <USER_ID>, // include only comments by this user
    'count' => true // it will return only count of comments and not the comments
) );
echo $count;
```

Comment: thank you very much. but is it possible that <USER_ID> get automaticly in author page. because i dont want to insert user id manuallu. thank for attention

Comment: Yes. If you're placing this code in author.php (author's archive) you can use `get_queried_object_id()` to get the ID of author.

Comment: Thanks so much. it works.. God bless you